# Delete files with name starting with X older than Y days

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to delete some files where their name start's with "Archive-Security*" and older than 5 days.

I've used the following cmd but it returns "ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria."

**forfiles -m "Archive-Security-*" -d -5 -c "cmd /c del @path"**

Comment: Your files don't have extensions? Try `Blah*.*`.

Comment: Yes they do have extensions. The complete file name of one of the files is as follow "Archive-Security-2016-02-29-20-47-57-481.etvx"

Comment: `Archive-Security-*.etvx` or `Archive-Security-*.*`

Comment: `forfiles`, `dir` and like commands should give the same result for both `somethig*.*` and `somethig*`. No need to use trailing `.*`. There must be another cause…

Comment: Replace `del` with `echo` to see which files are used. `forfiles -m "Archive-Security-*" -d -5 -c "cmd /c echo @path"`

Comment: Maybe test it without the double-quotes and not ```-m```, ```-d``` or ```-c``` but ```/m```, ```/d``` and ```/c```. I did a test with ```ForFiles /m myfileHere-* /d -5 /c "cmd /c del @path"```, and it works perfectly. [Link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles#BKMK_examples)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have either solved this or it is no longer a problem, but here would be a way to accomplish the task. This can be used in a .bat file script.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -File -Filter 'Archive-Security-*' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object {" ^
            "if ((($(Get-Date) - $_.LastAccessTime).Days) -gt 5) {" ^
                "Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -WhatIf" ^
            "}" ^
        "}"
```

Of course, using PowerShell directly would be easier.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter 'Archive-Security-*' |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ((($(Get-Date) - $_.LastAccessTime).Days) -gt 5) {
           Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -WhatIf
        }
    }
```